# Why is my C# web project looking for a local file once it is uploaded to remote server (with code behind)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

I am developing a c# site using VS 2015 Express. Everything works fine locally - I add a web for, the web form is accessible and can access the local SQL db and display the results from a simple SELECT statement. When I upload the forms to the web server and try to access the new web form I get a "The system cannot find the file specified" exception and shows the exception trace. The trace shows that the app is looking for a function within the new web form but in my local directory:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +362
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>      System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +120
>      System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +160
>      System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +108
>      KirkEB2017.WaterList.getData() in **C:\Users\Kirk\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\KirkEB2017\KirkEB2017\WaterList.aspx**.cs:79
>      KirkEB2017.WaterList.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in **C:\Users\Kirk\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\KirkEB2017\KirkEB2017\WaterList.aspx**.cs:22
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2952

Please help! This seems to me like it may be something simple I'm forgetting...very frustrating!

Here is the code from WaterList.aspx.cs:

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Sql;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Text;

    namespace KirkEB2017
    {
        public partial class WaterList : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                if (!this.IsPostBack)
                {
                    //fill the water data table
                    DataTable dt = this.getData();

                    //build the HTML string for the DT
                    StringBuilder sbHTML = new StringBuilder();

                    //table start
                    sbHTML.Append("<table border='1'>");

                    //header row
                    sbHTML.Append("<tr>");
                    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        sbHTML.Append("<th>");
                        sbHTML.Append(column.ColumnName);
                        sbHTML.Append("</th>");
                    }

                    sbHTML.Append("</tr>");

                    // Data Rows
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        sbHTML.Append("<tr>");
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            sbHTML.Append("<td>");
                            sbHTML.Append(row[col.ColumnName]);
                            sbHTML.Append("</td>");
                        }
                        sbHTML.Append("</tr>");

                    }
                    //table end
                    sbHTML.Append("</table>");


                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = sbHTML.ToString() });

                }


            }

            private DataTable getData()
            {

                KBData kbData = new KBData();
                SqlConnection sqlConn = kbData.KBConnect();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT BrandName, flouride FROM tbl_Water"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }

                    }
                }   


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post actual code from the WaterList.aspx.cs file?

Comment: The error doesn't mean that it didn't find a function nor that it's looking for anything in your local files. It's just debug information that is written at compile time and that's where the built code originated from.

Comment: To the Author, this is a dup because your code is not throwing or catching an exception but was in the call chain when an exception was handled and a stack trace was generated; during which the system tries to capture details like class and source location.  When you build your files you used debug-mode which retains the source location info.  Try doing a Release build and deploying that.

Comment: Thank you Kelly! That was what I was forgetting to do. Works great now.